# R find elements with digits and "," only

Tags: r, regex

I have a list like this:

```
 [1] "IIB"                        "142 min"                    "\nDrama            "        "2,315,883"                 
 [5] "$28.34M"                    "IIB"                        "175 min"                    "\nCrime, Drama            "
 [9] "1,599,110"                  "$134.97M"
```

I want to find the indexes of elements with digits and "," only, that is 4 and 9.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
grep('^[-,0-9]+$', x)
#[1] 4 9
```

I have also included `-` for negative numbers.

The `stringr` equivalent is `str_which` :

```
stringr::str_which(x, '^[-,0-9]+$')
```

**data**

```
x <- c("IIB", "142 min", "\nDrama            ", "2,315,883", "$28.34M", 
"IIB", "175 min", "\nCrime, Drama            ", "1,599,110", "$134.97M")
```